# I need help with solving one Omar Al-Khayyam's distinct cubic equation, $x^3+ax^2=c$.

Tags: geometry, conic-sections

The cubic equation of interest is $x^3+2x^2=6$.  I found the two conics. The parabola is $y= x^2$ and the rectangular parabola, $(x+2)y=6$. I am familiar with the geometry of the parabola and can graph the rectangular hyperbola with the center at $(-2,0)$. I have been studying the works of Apollonius. In particular, the use of equal, area rectangles. I am graphing it geometrically and trying to see the relationship.

Comment: Your cubic has exactly one real root, namely $x=1.34025083013$. There is a formula for solving a cubic. Please use MathJax. Here is a
[tutorial](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference).

Comment: If you found the conics and can graph them, what else do you need?

Comment: First: thank you for mentioning _Omar Al-Khayyam_, was very interesting to read about him. Next: in your query you describe what you did and found so far, thus you do have a solution (a graphical at least, like Omar Al-Khayyam), insofar I don't undestand what else you need.

Comment: I want to show the equation with segment lengths that are constructed with the properties of the rectangular hyperbola and the parabola. I am establishing the ratios and proportions. I have a top-level approach but now I need to develop the details.

Comment: I looked up how Khayyam solved that equation: his conics are not exactly the same as yours. Is that your problem? Or something else? Please EDIT your question to explain in more detail what you need.

Comment: I am interested in what conics he used. The cubic equation that I used is x^3+2x^2=6. I used the parabola, y=x^2 and the rectangular hyperbola, (x+2) y=6. Using substitution, this gave me x^3+2x^2=6 with the intersection at x=1.34025 and y = 1.79627. According to Apollonius, the product of the distances of any point on the hyperbola to its asymptotes is equal to a constant.  I am currently working on the circle that contains these two points, the point of intersection of the parabola and rectangular hyperbola and another point on the hyperbola. Using this, I can establish ratios/ proportions.

Comment: Don't you have Khayyam's text? Anyway, the conics he uses can be expressed as $xy=\root{3}\of{6^2}$ and $y^2=(x+2)\root{3}\of6$.

Comment: I don't have any of his texts. I have solved several thus far with my knowledge of Greek geometry and the study of Apollonius. The conics you mentioned will work but, even knowing the conics, you need to be very good with Greek geometry and the geometry of conics.  I will let you know how I progress with my equations.

Comment: See here: https://archive.org/details/lalgbredomaralk00khaygoog/page/n66/mode/1up

Answer (score 0):

As Dietrich Burde commented, there is a formula for solving cubics. See [here](https://math.vanderbilt.edu/schectex/courses/cubic/) and [here](https://www.math.utah.edu/%7Ewortman/1060text-tcf.pdf). A suggestion is rearranging to $x^3+2x^2-6=0$. Using Decartes' rule of signs, we also know there is 1 positive root which is $x \approx 1.34$. The other roots are complex as shown in the image below. Hope this helps, try using the formula. If you have trouble with that then I suggest using the Newton-Raphson method or substitution (harder)

[image]

Comment: Thank you. I can get the roots of the equation but am trying to solve it with only geometry.

Answer (score 0):

Complex roots can be found by trigonometric function trick...
$$x^3+2x^2-6=0.$$
Let $x=\frac{3}{2\sin t}$. Then,
$$\frac{9}{4}+3\sin t-4\sin^3t=0$$
$$\frac94+\sin3t=0$$
$$t=-\frac13\arcsin(\tfrac{9}{4})$$
$$t=-\frac\pi 6+\frac i3\ln(\tfrac{\sqrt{65}+9}{4})$$
$$\sin t=...$$
So on. By hand it is complicated.

Edit: For the real root, we take $t=-\frac \pi 6+
\frac i3\ln(\tfrac{\sqrt{65}+9}{4})\color{red}{+\frac{2\pi}{3}}$ so the real root is
$$x=\frac3{2\cosh\left(\frac1 3\ln(\tfrac{\sqrt{65}+9}{4})\right)}\approx 1.3402508$$